# On fresh install of conda getting error ResolvePackageNotFound for conda itself

Tags: conda, miniconda, conda-forge

I have done a fresh install of conda using an installer which had conda version 4.8.5 and set it to use conda-forge. After getting the install setup I did

```
conda update --all
```

Conda updated to 4.9.0. Now when I try to install anything I am getting

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - conda==4.8.5
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What does your ~/.condarc file look like?

Comment: _After getting the install setup I did_ Did you execute that in the base environment? It would be much better to use `conda update -n base conda` in order to update Conda. _Now when I try to install anything I am getting_ Where are you trying to install new packages?

Comment: My .condarc is as follows,```auto_activate_base: false
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
channel-priority: flexible```.

Comment: I didn't have base activated when doing ```conda update --all```. I was trying to install the new packages into base. I had to do ```conda install conda=4.8.5``` to be able to install the new packages. Every time I installed a new package conda would update to v4.9.0 and then I'd have to downgrade again. After doing this 3 times, now I am not getting the error, even though conda version is at 4.9.0